# Sort a Huge file

Tags: perl, sorting, ksh

I want to sort a huge file of approx 20M rows:

- ascending on Team Name and
- then descending on highest score.

so I can get the highest scorers per team.

I want to be considerate of system's resources.  So...

1. Is there a way to do this without putting all the data into a hash/array in Perl?
2. Can we do this using the Unix/Linux sort utility?

If so, can you please show how to do it?

My input-file will be about 20M rows in the following format

```
Chicago Bulls|Michael Jordan|38
LA Lakers|Kobe Bryant|32
Chicago Bulls|Steve Kerr|16
LA Lakers|Paul Gasol|20
LA Lakers|Shaquile ONeal|19
Chicago Bulls|Scottie Pippen|23
.
.
.
```

Comment: Use database, they are made for such tasks. :)

Comment: Actually I'm getting this data out of a MySQL DB.  But the DBA is pushing back saying that this is better done in the App layer.  The SQL for ranking each player within a team and getting top 3 scorers per team in MySQL has sub-queries, order by, having... etc... which the DBAs are pushing back on.

Comment: Consider to change DBA. This is half a joke, but seriously I wouldn't expect such an answer from someone who is DBA.

Comment: The data appears to already be sorted by score (3rd col), is that so for all of it? If so you just need a stable sort of the first column: `sort -s -t\| -k1 file.in`

Comment: No it's not sorted by score (col 3). Please check again.

Comment: >.< Not sure what I was looking at

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?  If you want the top 3 scorers per team, but, say, three players are tied for second place.

Comment: According to [this page on dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) it's as easy as: `SELECT team, name, score FROM basketball ORDER BY team, score DESC;`. If that is enough to cause a noticeable slowdown in your Database, there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to sort.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;
my %high_score;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($team_name, $player, $score) = split(/\|/);
    for ($high_score{$team_name}{$player}) {
        $_ = $score
            unless $_ && $_ > $score
    }
}

for my $team_name (sort keys %high_score) {
    my %team_scores = %{ $high_score{$team_name} };
    my @top_players = sort { $team_scores{$b} <=>  $team_scores{$a} } (keys %team_scores);

    my $n = 0;
    for my $player (@top_players) {
        print "$team_name, $player high score: $team_scores{$player}\n";
        last if ++$n >= 2;
    }
}

__DATA__
Chicago Bulls|Michael Jordan|38
Chicago Bulls|Scottie Pippen|23
Chicago Bulls|Poor Joe|10
Chicago Bulls|Steve Kerr|16
LA Lakers|Kobe Bryant|32
LA Lakers|Paul Gasol|20
LA Lakers|Shaquile ONeal|19
```

Edits: (1) updated requirements (2) s/while/for/

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The original intent is to pick the top 2 (or any number) players from every team and write it out to a file.  It's not to find the top score+player from each team.

Comment: thanks!! can you explain what you're doing in $_ = $score unless $_ && $_ > $score.

Comment: This statement is effectively finding the  maximum. It saves `$score` when it is greater than $score{$team_name}{$player}. Note that $_ is aliased to $high_score{$team_name}{$player}, so that assigning to $_ also updates the hash entry.

Comment: So, if I have a file w/ 20M rows, putting them all in to a hash won't take up all (or a lot of) memory?

Comment: It's optimized to only keep the maximum value for each player, so should be reasonably memory-efficient. The other thing to watch for that the input file is read sequentially and not loaded into memory. I've changed my answer to read via a `for` loop to a `while` loop to ensure this.

Comment: +1  FWIW, you don't need that %team_scores copy — you can `keys %{$HoH->{foo}}` directly.  (Hmm, re-keying `$high_score{$team}` hashrefs as `...->{score}->{player}` would be somewhat more memory efficient, too, since you'd only need up to N _score_ keys)  Also, an array slice (`@top_players[0..$limit]`) would be more readable/idiomatic IMHO than that `last if ++$n >= $limit` logic.

Comment: @phil. Fair enough. However,  I didn't see the need to micro-optimize the second loop. I'm also adverse to splicing as this pads with undefs when there there are two few results for a given team.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if `sort` will break with such a big file, but you can try following command. It separates fields with pipe, then sort by first field and by third field numerically in reverse order, (`-r`), descendant:

```
sort -t'|' -k1,1 -k3,3nr infile
```

It yields:

```
Chicago Bulls|Michael Jordan|38
Chicago Bulls|Scottie Pippen|23
Chicago Bulls|Steve Kerr|16
LA Lakers|Kobe Bryant|32
LA Lakers|Paul Gasol|20
LA Lakers|Shaquile ONeal|19
```

Comment: I've used sort for large inputs like this in the past, its generally pretty efficient

Comment: can I sort ascending on field1 and descending on field3?  the -r will cause reverse sorting on both the fields...correct?

Comment: @Birei  Your suggestion is yielding the following results.

Comment: sort -t'|' -k1,1 -nk3,1 players.in

Comment: Chicago Bulls|Steve Kerr|16  <br>
LA Lakers|Shaquile ONeal|19  
LA Lakers|Paul Gasol|20  
Chicago Bulls|Scottie Pippen|23  
LA Lakers|Kobe Bryant|32  
Chicago Bulls|Michael Jordan|38

Comment: @MyFirstNameMyLastName: Sorry, I think it was incorrect. I've fixed it. I hope it works now.

Comment: @Birei: Thanks!! That works. So, for the n and r options to be only on the 2nd key I should append it at the end of the key without any spaces?

Comment: You can speed up sort by telling it to use more RAM with the `-S` option. Put the whole file in RAM if you can spare it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can tell `sort` to sort ascending in one column and descending in another. However, you can use two `sorts` in a pipeline using the `-s` option for stable sorting:

```
sort -t\| -rnk3 file.in | sort -st\| -k1
```

Comment: if the numbers are floating point... say 0.02, 0.5, 20.5 does it not sort correctly if we use the -n option?  I've tried and it's not.

Comment: it worked for floating point as well.  I needed to give the -k3,1 and -k1,1 for it to work correctly.

Comment: sort -t\| -rnk3,1 file.in.unsorted | sort -st\| -k1,1 > file.in.sorted